# Need to call an api to refresh token in android mvvm using retrofit ,where to write the logic?

Tags: android, api, mvvm, retrofit, token

At the time of login we get a authorization token and a refresh token,authorization token is attached with all API in header ,but after some time **authorization token will expire and we will get 401**,to refresh we need to call a API with refresh token that we get at the time of login in response we will get a new authorization token and refresh token,problem is where to catch 401 and write at **one point to call refresh token API** and resend the previous failed API ,we cant call API  in interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Refresh Access Token globally (Separate logic as a module) using RxJava 2, RxAndroid 2 and Retrofit 2](https://android.jlelse.eu/refresh-access-token-globally-using-rxjava-2-rxandroid-2-and-retrofit-2-fba6be0f11bd) post. 
Maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Okhttp (which acts as the http layer of retrofit) has a mechanism for doing just this. Have a look at https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-authenticator/

You provide the Authenticator to your Okhttp builder during setup and this then responds to 401 error responses to fetch a refresh token.